# gaps between horizontal lines in table

Tags: tables, captions, footnotes, hline

Hello I would like to replicate this table

[image]

I already made something that looks like this:

[image]

There are a few things that bother me

- My caption is longer than horizontal lines
- gaps between the first row and both above and below `\hline` are too small
- I would also like to add something similar to `\footnotesize{}` below the table to add the source

Here is my code:

Edit I just managed to add the source

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Przyporządkowanie obiektów modelu logicznego i fizycznego}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
   \hline 
   \textbf{Obiekty modelu logicznego} & \textbf{Obiekty modelu fizycznego} \\  \hline \vspace{0.2cm}
    Encja & Tabela \\ \vspace{0.2cm}
    
    Atrybut encji & Kolumna tabeli \\ \vspace{0.2cm}
    
    Identyfikator encji & Klucz główny tabeli \\ \vspace{0.2cm}
    
    Związek & Klucz obcy i reguły integralności \\
    
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\vspace{-0.5cm}
{\hspace{+4.5cm} \footnotesize Źródło: Opracowanie własne}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with the `caption` and `booktabs` packages. The latter adds some vertical padding around its horizontal rules.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{booktabs, caption}
    \usepackage{copyrightbox}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering\captionsetup{font=small}
    \caption{Przyporządkowanie obiektów modelu logicznego i fizycznego}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
       \toprule
       \textbf{Obiekty modelu logicznego} & \textbf{Obiekty 
       modelu fizycznego} \\ 
       \midrule
        Encja & Tabela \\[0.2cm]
        Atrybut encji & Kolumna tabeli \\[0.2cm]
        Identyfikator encji & Klucz główny tabeli \\[0.2cm]
        Związek & Klucz obcy i reguły integralności \\
        \bottomrule\addlinespace[0.5ex]
    \multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\footnotesize Źródło: Opracowanie własne}
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:1}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `\tabularray` and `copyright` packages:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \SetTblrStyle{head}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}

\copyrightbox[b]{
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Przyporządkowanie obiektów modelu logicznego i fizycznego},
  label = {table:1}
                ]{colspec={l l},
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
                  }
   \toprule
Obiekty modelu logicznego   
                    &   Obiekty modelu fizycznego       \\
   \midrule
Encja               &   Tabela                          \\
Atrybut encji       &   Kolumna tabeli                  \\ 
Identyfikator encji & Klucz główny tabeli               \\ 
Związek             & Klucz obcy i reguły integralności \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}}{\hfill\footnotesize Źródło: Opracowanie własne}    
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the `copyrightbox` package I did not know. Merci !